# Display hours/minutes format in datetime?

Tags: vb.net

I had datetime and I set its format to `Time` and `showupdown` to **true**. But I can't get to display Hours/Minute Format.

Is there a way to change its format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't get to display Hours/Minute Format

You have to apply the correct [`CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)  to the `DateTimePicker`. Also remember to set the `DatetimePicker.Format` to `Custom`.

In designer or constructor:

```
myDatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
myDatePicker.CustomFormat = "HH/mm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.Beginner, 
I assume you mean the control datetimepicker that you are trying to use. You want it to display the hour and minute like this?

9:53

One way to do this is to feed it the information for only what you wnat displayed:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
Dim d As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim i As Integer = d.Minute Mod 15
If (i > 0) Then
    DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(15 - i).AddSeconds(-d.Second)
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!